# $(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)=8abc\; (a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}^{+})$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: number-theory

Prove that:
$$(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)=8abc,\quad a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$$
has an infinite number of solutions $(a,b,c)$.

Now we found this infinite 
$$(a,b,c)=(\dfrac{4p}{p^2+1},\dfrac{p^2-3}{3p^2-1},\dfrac{(p+1)(p^2-4p+1)}{(p-1)(p^2+4p+1)}),p>2+\sqrt{3},p\in\mathbb {Q}^{+}$$

> My Question: Have other form solution?

Comment: Does $Q^+=\mathbb{Q}^+$? What is an array of solution?

Comment: mean:thie equation have many$(a,b,c)\in Q^{+}$solution

Comment: Source? Effort? Reason for interest? Voting to close.

Comment: You are posting a large number of unsourced, unmotivated problems with no hint of having put any effort into any of them. That's not the intended use of this website.

Comment: There are three upvotes and 4 people have favorited the question.  I don't think we should close it just because we don't like the way it was asked.

Comment: Just to understand notation, we assume $0\notin \mathbb{Q}^+$?

Comment: You got any positive integer solution for this?

Comment: @Jim, how about closing it because OP is unresponsive to comments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The OP is not the only person that benefits from this question.  Now 5 people have favorited it.

Comment: @Jim, you're looking at one question --- I'm looking at the whole site. I don't want people posting lots of unsourced, unmotivated, effort-free problems and then walking away from them. If you have a better idea than threatening with closure, I'm eager to see it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My idea is to not threaten with closure and let people use the site as they please.  You are perfectly willing to ignore questions that you feel are unsourced, unmotivated, or effort-free.

Comment: Also if you think those are valid reasons to close a question why not try and get them included as reasons to close, instead of misusing the reasons that are there.

Comment: @Jim, I'm sure there are some uses of this site that you would not want people to engage in. You and I just disagree on exactly which uses are, and which aren't, to be considered acceptable. And that kind of thing gets decided by the community as a whole. The community does not seem to be interested in closing this question, so that's one for your side. See also the discussion at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/academic-integrity

Comment: Interestingly, the [same question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208485/find-all-solution-a-b-c-with-1-a21-b21-c2-8abc) was asked 14 hours ago on MathOverflow, where it was immediately put on hold as off-topic, despite the following comment by Gerry Myerson: "Why is an answer in a comment a reason for closure as off-topic?".

Comment: yes, these days  I suddenly go on to research the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are nontrivial rational solutions, for example $$(a,b,c)=(5/6,\ 2/11,\ 3/13).$$ Note that the equation may be written as 
$$[1]\ \ \frac{1-a^2}{2a}\cdot \frac{1-b^2}{2b} \cdot \frac{1-c^2}{2c}=1.$$
The following is *only an idea* of how to find an infinite number of pairs $(a,b)$ for which $(a,b,5/6)$ is a solution. Define $$f(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{2x},$$ and note that $f(p/q)=(q^2-p^2)/(2pq).$ Also note that if $f(p/q)=m/n$ then also $f((q-p)/(q+p))=n/m,$ so that we may invert one of the fractions in working with the equation.

If we can find infinitely many rational pairs $(x,y)$ for which
$$[2]\ \ \frac{1-x^2}{2x}\cdot \frac{2y}{1-y^2}=\frac{6}{5},$$ this will produce infinitely many rational solutions to [1], by the above remark about inverting fractions taken on by $f$  via the map $p/q \to (q-p)/(q+p).$

Now [2] is a cubic curve
$$kx-y+x^2y-ky^2=0,$$ where $k=6/5.$ It has a rational point on it taken from the solution $(5/6,2/11,3/13)$ to [1].

I think this means there are infinitely many rational points on [2]. From the single rational point $P$, use of the tangent line will give another, say $Q$; then use of the tangent line there will give a third point $R$, and after that one has two rational points $Q,R$ for which the curve is not tangent to line $QR$, so the line through those gives yet another point, etc. I am not expert enough on cubic curves to be able to definitely say this will give infinitely many rational points. Maybe someone who knows cubic curves can make this argument go through.

Comment: why,$kx-y+x^2y-ky^2=0$ has infinitely many rational solutions.

Comment: @math110 There are standard ways to get more rational solutions to a cubic once one has a starting solution. The topic is I believe "elliptic curves" to look up. However as I note at the end of my answer, I am not expert enough to *guarantee* for this example one will get infinitely many rational solutions.

Comment: so I can't understand your this .But Thank you for your solution

Comment: @math110 What do you mean by "can't understand"? Did you try by looking up elliptic curves to see what I mean?

Comment: I known some reslut with elliptic curves theory,But I can't use this theory to find solution,can you post your solution( one form)

Comment: @math110 I'll have a look at this again (it has been a while since I looked before at it) and will add something to the answer if I get some examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24535/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-math110).

Answer (score 1):

The equation,

$$(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)-8abc=0$$

is just a quadratic in any of the variables. Hence,

$$c=\frac{8ab\pm y}{2(-1+a^2+b^2-a^2b^2)}$$

where,

$$64a^2b^2-4(-1+a^2+b^2-a^2b^2)(1-a^2-b^2+a^2b^2) = y^2$$

This *quartic* polynomial to be made a square is easily reducible to an elliptic curve. From initial rational point {$a,b$} = {$5/6,\; 2/11$}, one can find an infinite more.

Comment: See all http://mathoverflow.net/a/225467/12905